# How to dd a remote disk using SSH on local machine and save to a local disk

Tags: ssh, hard-disk, remote, dd

How can I create a backup of a remote disk using SSH on my local machine and save it to a local disk?

---

I've tried the following:

```
ssh hostname@my.ip.address "sudo dd if=/dev/sdX " | \
  dd of=/home/username/Documents/filename.image`
```

However, I receive the following error:

> no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 186, accepted):

If your intent is to backup a remote computer's **HDD A** via SSH to a single file that's on your local computer's HDD, you could do one of the following.

#### Examples

*run from remote computer*

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | ssh user@local dd of=image.gz
```

*run from local computer*

```
$ ssh user@remote "dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz
```

#### Live example

```
$ ssh skinner "dd if=/dev/sda5 | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz
208782+0 records in
208782+0 records out
106896384 bytes (107 MB) copied, 22.7608 seconds, 4.7 MB/s
116749+1 records in
116749+1 records out
59775805 bytes (60 MB) copied, 23.9154 s, 2.5 MB/s

$ ll | grep image.gz
-rw-rw-r--.   1 saml saml  59775805 May 31 01:03 image.gz
```

#### Methods for monitoring?

1. Login via `ssh` in another terminal and `ls -l` the file to see what it's size is.
2. You can use `pv` to monitor the progress of a large dd operation, for instance, for the remote example above, you can do:

   ```
    $ dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | pv | ssh user@local dd of=image.gz
   ```
3. Send a "SIGUSR1" signal to `dd` and it will print stats. Something like:

   ```
    $ pkill -USR1 dd
   ```
4. Use `dd`'s progress switch, `status=progress`

#### References

The methods mentioned above for monitoring were originally left via comments by [@Ryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112595/ryan) & [@bladt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/63905/bladt) and myself. I've moved them into the answer to make them more obvious.

Comment: I tried this for a similar problem (backing up remote computer `ONE`'s hard drive to remote computer `TWO`'s storage), like this:<br 
/>[root@ONE]# dd if=/dev/sda1 | ssh root@TWO `dd of=/root/Public/ONE/sda1.img`<br 
/>
   409600+0 records in

   409600+0 records out

   209715200 bytes (210 MB) copied, 0.894929 s, 234 MB/s

   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

   root@TWO's password:

The problem is that the `/root/Public/ONE/sda1.img` file was created on `ONE`, not on `TWO` as expected.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Can someone give us an example of using `pv` from the local machine? Thank you.

Comment: it is better to use lbzip2 or pigz insted of gzip

Comment: why do i need " | dd of=image.gz" at end? (not just ">image.gz") because dd takes 100% of one cpu

Comment: Regarding monitoring: Newer dd versions also have the `status=progress` option. Thus, you do not need to run `pkill -USR1 dd` from another terminal anymore.

Comment: I only have tar on my old macOS. I know how to use tar, but I’m having trouble translating your command into tar’s format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: excellent work around. thanks

Comment: restore: gunzip -c xxx.gz | pv | dd of=/dev/sda1

Comment: you also want to bs=1M in there because by default dd will copy in 512 byte chunks. 1M much faster.

Comment: Is it safe to read /dev/sda if the machine is actively booted from it?

Answer (score 15):

The error you receive is due to the use of sudo remotely (you'd be asked for the password but you don't have a tty to enter it). On the other hand, as a normal user you can't normally use simply `dd` as suggested in other answer (you don't have the required permissions to the device).
You can solve the problem by giving yourself rights to execute `dd` as sudo without a password. You can do this by editing the sudoers file (on the remote!):

`sudo visudo`

add the following line:

`userfoo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/dd if=/dev/sdX`

Now you can issue:

`ssh userfoo@host "sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/sdX" | dd of=test.dd`

and it should work.
You could make a more generic entry in sudoers, allowing you to run `dd` with any parameter, but it is wiser to keep this free permissions to the minimum you need.

Comment: Or, you can just run 'sudo ls' at the applicable end (and type in password), just prior to running the 'sudo dd ...' command

Comment: With newer versions of dd adding status=progress even allows monitoring of copy progress.

Comment: This is the correct answer regarding the error message. But you could add these alternatives: use `ssh -t` to execute the command with a `tty` allowing for interactive password input / use `sudo -S` to read password from `stdin` even without a `tty`.

Comment: @MikeW note that this might not work since by default `sudo` only remembers the authentication for the same console session, see `timeout_type` in `man 5 sudoers`.

Answer (score 8):

I've just used a modified version on a virtual Linux Mint box to clone a physical hard drive on an aging RedHat server.

I ran the following as root on the virtual box:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.5 "dd if=/dev/cciss/c0d0" | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

- 192.168.1.5 is the physical Red Hat Enterprise Linux 2.1 box.
- /dev/sdb is a new virtual disk, which when finished cloning will be the basis of a virtual version of the old dying physical box.

Answer (score 7):

Combining these answers allowed me to clone to another Linux host and avoid the 'permission denied' error:

- RPI4 SD card (`/dev/mmcblk0` - this clones the entire card)
- avoid permission issue by prompting for elevated privilege (`sudo -S`)
- see progress as it copies (`status=progress`)
- compressing the copy (`gzip`)
- specify buffer size (`bs=64k`) for improved speed. You can specify higher values. please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322224/439775)

```bsh
ssh user@1.1.1.1 "sudo -S dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=64k status=progress | gzip -1 -" | dd of=rpiimg.gz bs=64k
```

Comment: great - works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation recently. The difference for me was, that

- due to security measures `root` `ssh` access was disabled
- `sudo` was not installed (deliberately)

So what I did was:

1. examine device file permissions (grep for appropriate block device naming sheme (`hd`, `sd`, `nvme`, etc.))

```bsh
user@machine:~$ ls -la /dev/ |grep sd
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,   0 Nov 22 13:36 sda
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,   1 Nov 22 13:36 sda1
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,   2 Nov 22 13:36 sda2
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,   5 Nov 22 13:36 sda5
```

2. add the user to the `disk` group

```bsh
root@machine:~$ usermod -aG user disk
```

3. then run the `dd` the same way you already tried (but w/o `sudo`)

```bsh
ssh user@my.ip.address "dd if=/dev/sdX " |  dd of=/home/username/Documents/filename.image
```

(or also chain-in the `gzip` as others suggested)