# How can I tell whether dd is done erasing my hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, dd, disk

I'm using `dd` to overwrite my hard drive with zeros (before I recycle my laptop).

Several minutes into running, the visual display was replaced with a black background and a flashing cursor in the top left of the screen.

No text is being written to the screen, so it's not clear to me whether `dd` is still running or how to tell when it stops.

Comment: linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `dd` has written the device full it will output a message:

```
dd: writing to '/dev/full': No space left on device
```

Sending `USR1` signal to running `dd` process makes it output the current status. You can use `kill` to send the signal:

```
kill -USR1 $PID
```

More recent versions of GNU [`dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) have an option `status=progress` which will show the current progress on terminal.

Wiping disk is likely faster with `cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdX` instead of `dd` when `dd` parameters aren't tuned:

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdX
```

You can get a progress bar if you have [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) installed:

```
pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdX
```

Comment: i mean literally there is nothing there but a single black screen with a flashing cursor.  i'm not in a terminal window.  i have no access to any programs, no ability to open a new terminal.

Comment: does this mean something has gone wrong?

Comment: Are you running `dd` from the disk your system installation is on?

Comment: yeah, it's the only disk on my laptop.  i'm trying to wipe the whole laptop.  maybe this was a dumb way to do it -- i dunno, i'm not experienced in this.

Comment: You should have used live-cd/usb etc. instead. Kernel likely doesn't like the file system vanishing under it while in use. Its still likely a good idea to boot from live (usb/cd) media and run the wipe from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64911/discussion-between-sebasth-and-dbliss).

Comment: cat is not faster.

Comment: @user2497 reworded the sentence. Without tuning dd parameters, I've observed cat being always faster than dd. Default block size (bs) for dd is 512, increasing it has a significant impact. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322223/why-dd-takes-too-long

Answer (score 0):

How can I tell whether dd is done erasing my hard drive?

You can use the [`dcfldd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dcfldd.1.html) tool

> dcfldd - enhanced version of dd for forensics and security

[dcfldd features](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dcfldd)

> dcfldd was initially developed at Department of Defense Computer Forensics Lab (DCFL). This tool is based on the dd program with the following additional features:
>
> - Hashing on-the-fly: dcfldd can hash the input data as it is being
>     transferred, helping to ensure data integrity.
>
>   - **Status output: dcfldd can update the user of its progress in terms of the amount of data transferred and how much longer operation will take.**
>   - Flexible disk wipes: dcfldd can be used to wipe disks quickly and with a
>       known pattern if desired.
>   - Image/wipe verify: dcfldd can verify that a target drive is a bit-for-bit
>       match of the specified input file or pattern.
>   - Multiple outputs: dcfldd can output to multiple files or disks at the same
>       time.
>   - Split output: dcfldd can split output to multiple files with more
>       configurability than the split command.
>   - Piped output and logs: dcfldd can send all its log data and output to
>       commands as well as files natively.