# How to clone remote Linux system and make an image file with it locally?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, dd

This question has bothered me for a while.

I have a remote machine with CentOS, which can only be accessed via `ssh`. I need to clone everything this system has and replicate it in my local with `virtualbox`. Here is what did:

1. Clone the system by following steps/commands (`dd`) mentioned in [this article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk). The command looks like this:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/xvda of=xvda.raw
   ```
2. Transfer the dumped file to my local, and convert it to VDI format after reading [this page](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/04/29/virtualbox-convert-raw-image-to-vdi-and-otherwise/):

   ```
   VBoxManage convertdd xvda.raw xvda.vdi --format VDI
   ```
3. Create a VM with `xvda.vdi`

The VM cannot be launched, showing black screen and saying "Press any key to continue...".

**Updated:**
See below dump from the remote machine. It seems there's no boot partition exists in the remote machine. If this, how can I create a boot partition in my local VM and clone all other partitions (I guess it's all about `/dev/xvda`) from remote machine?

```
[tom@ip-10-203-0-000 ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/xvda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00057cbb

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1               1        3917    31456256   83  Linux

[tom@ip-10-203-0-000 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       30G  9.2G   19G  33% /
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing a boot loader.
You'll probably want to go with `dd if=/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda1`. Maybe you'll want to use some `stop` argument to prevent from dumping further than your bootloader and first partition.

---

Update:

Reading your `df` output, I'm guessing your source instance is something like a Xen Paravirtualized domU, which means there's no guarantee your instance has a bootloader or even a kernel. I'ld bet that a `ls /dev/xvd*` would only show partitions and no devices. And maybe you even have a `/proc/xen` directory?

Assuming the latter is true, then you should investigate on Xen PV to VirtualBox conversion. Which would probably involve installing a kernel and bootloader prior to dumping your partition. Make sure to backup your instance before breaking anything, ...

Also: your initial post told about dumping `sda1`, your edit shows a `xvda1`, ... Are you sure you are dumping the right partition?

Comment: @vlastimi, thanks but can you please share more details? I yet used these commands very often.

Comment: I actually tried >dd if=/dev/sda as well but no luck. Please share the full command as you mentioned. Appreciate that!

Comment: ...or you could install a new boot loader. You have the partition, assuming all good, boot using a live OS and reinstall grub.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. You are absolutely right. There're only partitions ls /dev/xvd* and /proc/xen does exist although the folder is empty. I'm not familiar with Xen PV and will install a boot loader as @jc__ said. BTW, all my work was about xvda than sda1. Updated the original post.

Comment: Finally changed direction and clone another vm which doesn't use Xen PV.