# How to scp from remote root directory (/)

Tags: scp

I am trying to scp from a remote and I want to copy the whole filesystem (it is a small embedded linux device). SCP does not like the way I am trying it:

```
scp -r name@ip:/ ./local_folder
```

I get the following error:

```
error: unexpected filename:
```

And if I run it with -v the last message looks like so:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f /
Entering directory: D0755 0 
Sink: D0755 0 
error: unexpected filename:
```

If I instead do

```
scp -r name@ip:/etc ./local_folder
```

The same debug snippet looks like this:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f /etc
Entering directory: D0755 0 etc
Sink: D0755 0 etc
```

It is kind of hard to search, I cannot find any people with the same problem if I try search terms like "scp root directory slash unexpected filename" etc.

Comment: Does "scp name@ip:/. ./local_folder" work?

Comment: No, same error
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f /.
Entering directory: D0755 0 .
Sink: D0755 0 .
error: unexpected filename: .

Comment: What about `scp -r name@ip:/* ./local_folder`?

Comment: @AdminBee quote that wildcard so the local shell doesn't attempt to evaluate it. `scp -r name@ip:'/*' ./local_folder`

Answer (score 2):

Since `scp` follows any encountered symbolic link, it would make more sense to use a tool that copies files as they are.

The `rsync` program is able to recreate a directory structure better than `scp`:

```bsh
rsync -av name@ip:/ ./local_folder
```

This not only preserves file metadata (timestamps etc.), but also copies hidden files found in the `/` directory (if there are any).

You may make `rsync` preserve hard links by additionally using `-H`.

`rsync` uses `ssh` as its default transport.

---

You could also use `tar` on the remote system, over `ssh`:

```bsh
ssh name@ip tar -c -f - -C / . >local_folder/filesystem.tar
```

or

```bsh
ssh name@ip tar -c -f - -C / . | tar -v -x -f - -C local_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

tldr: try `name@ip://` instead of `name@ip:/`

I was trying similar thing. I wanted to run an scp script using WINScp and without specifying default remote directory, my script always connected to the same, *seemingly random*, folder inside the file system. I guess it was a home directory for my `username`.

If the url ended with `/`, i.e `name@ip:/`, this resulted in connecting to that *random home directory*. Even if that directory didn't exist (which resulted in weird behaviour when executing some commands...). After executing `cd /` explicitly, I have been connected to the root directory.

After I changed the `/` into `//`, i.e. `name@ip://`, the scp connected to the root directory, without needing to execute `cd /`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scp -r name@ip:/. ./local_folder`.

Alternatively, the `dd` command can be used for bit by bit backups (See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk))

Comment: This does not work. Thanks for the dd suggestion but I actually want to actually inspect the filesystem

Answer (score -2):

AdminBee and roaima gave the right solution:

```
scp -r name@ip:'/*' ./local_folder
```

Allowed me to copy the whole file system (it also works without quotes btw)

Comment: Does this include any hidden names in the `/` directory?

Comment: It may do something entirely different without quotes. Consider `mkdir 'name@ip:'; touch 'name@ip:/boot'` and then rerun the `scp` command "without quotes". You'll be very disappointed because the `scp` will only copy from the `/boot` directory. ALWAYS quote wildcards when you don't want the local shell to try and expand them

Answer (score -2):

So actually, for what I wanted I found a much faster option, which also allowed me to ignore some files:

```
sshfs user@server: sshfsdir
rsync --recursive --exclude=whatever sshfsdir/path/on/server /where/to/store
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121337/recursively-use-scp-but-excluding-some-folders)

Comment: No... that's much slower than a solution that avoids the `sshfs` part. Just use `rsync -av user@server:/path/on/server/ /where/to/store`